# Running Total Using Self Join

Tags: sql

I have got a table here:

```
-----------+------------+--------+
| Company   |    Date    | Amount |
+-----------+------------+--------+
| A         | 22/07/2019 |     10 |
| A         | 22/07/2019 |      5 |
| A         | 23/07/2019 |     20 |
| A         | 23/07/2019 |      5 |
| B         | 22/07/2019 |     20 |
| B         | 22/07/2019 |     25 |
| B         | 23/07/2019 |     20 |
| B         | 23/07/2019 |      2 |
| B         | 23/07/2019 |      8 |
+-----------+------------+--------+
```

I want a running total at a company level and a date level. I want to write the query using a SELF JOIN. I have tried writing the query using Window function.

```
SELECT 
    company,
    date, 
    SUM(amount), SUM(SUM(amount)) OVER (ORDER BY date)running_total 
FROM 
    report 
GROUP BY  
    company, 
    date
ORDER BY 
    date;
```

The final result should look like:

```
+-----------+------------+--------+--------------+
| Company   |    Date    | Amount | RunningTotal |
+-----------+------------+--------+--------------+
| A         | 22/07/2019 |     15 |           15 |
| A         | 23/07/2019 |     25 |           40 |
| B         | 22/07/2019 |     45 |           45 |
| B         | 23/07/2019 |     30 |           75 |
+-----------+------------+--------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a self join.  SQL supports cumulative sums:

```
SELECT t.*,
       SUM(t.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY t.company ORDER BY t.date)
FROM t
ORDER BY t.date;
```

Comment: I understand that. But I am specifically looking to solve this problem using a Self Join.

Comment: @PrashantGupta: what's wrong with using a window function? That will usually be much more efficient than a self-join

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There is nothing wrong in using a window function. It's just that I have been asked to do the same using a Self Join.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works in SQL Server.

```
CREATE TABLE #test(Company varchar(30), Datevalue date, amount int)
INSERT INTO #test 
values ('A','2019-07-22',10),('A','2019-07-22',25)

SELECT company,amount, sum(amount) over(partition by company order by datevalue ROWS Unbounded preceding) as runningtotal
from #test
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point in doing this, but the following works:

```
select r1.company, r1."date", 
       sum(amount) as amount,
       (select sum(amount)
            from report r2
            where r2.date <= r1.date 
              and r2.company = r1.company) as running_total
from report r1
group by r1.company, r1."date"
order by r1.company, r1."date";
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/ONQM93216

Comment: Can you explain this part - 
(select sum(amount)
            from report r2
            where r2.date <= r1.date 
              and r2.company = r1.company) as running_total

Comment: @PrashantGupta: that's the self join you want

Comment: Yeah. But how is it functioning?

Comment: It's a self join that sums up all rows for the company of the main query that lie before that one. So that aggregation is run for each and every row that the main query returns.